# Crawl hidden parts from website

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrape articles and comments from [www.seeekingalpha.com](http://www.seekingalpha.com).
e.g. the article part and comments at [here](http://seekingalpha.com/article/3272165-weighing-the-week-ahead-what-does-the-greek-crisis-mean-for-financial-markets)

For the article part, I scraped them quite well with `Scrapy`, `webdriver` and `wget`(downloaded some html as well).

But for the comment part, things get hard.

1. When I directly access the page_source using Scrapy, the comment part will be hidden (no content). I was thinking that maybe the site recognizes my request as some non-browser one and refused to show them.
2. Then I used Chromeriver (from webdriver) to access the website, but ONLY the first page replied me with some comments, and never again.
3. Then I noticed that when I signed in using an account this issue can be avoided, but I can't find a way to sign in in a programmatic method, either to do this with 25 proxies.

I would like to know if I have gone into a wrong direction and if there is a way to dodge all these issues?

Comment: maybe it's using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Its a some ajax request which populates the page using [this url](http://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/hp_top_articles), the following demo in scrapy shell will help you to get your data.

```
scrapy shell 'http://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/hp_top_articles'
2015-06-22 10:43:26+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.6 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-06-22 10:43:26+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2015-06-22 10:43:26+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
2015-06-22 10:43:26+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2015-06-22 10:43:27+0530 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/hp_top_articles> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f2896c431d0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/hp_top_articles>
[s]   response   <200 http://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/hp_top_articles>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f289ebad450>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x7f2895e356d0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: import json

In [2]: cleaned_data  = response.body.strip('SA.Pages.HP.TopArticles.onupdate(').strip(')') 

In [3]: data = json.loads(clea)
%clear        cleaned_data  

In [3]: data = json.loads(cleaned_data)
```

if you print the data you will get something like the following,

```
[{u'author_name': None,
  u'author_picture': u'http://static1.cdn-seekingalpha.com/images/users_profile/003/022/051/medium_pic.png?1379847453',
  u'comments_counts': u'13',
  u'company_name': u'BlackBerry Ltd.',
  u'id': 3273215,
  u'path': u'/article/3273215-blackberry-brace-yourself-for-another-ugly-quarter',
  u'publish_on': 1434944662,
  u'slug': u'bbry',
  u'title': u'BlackBerry: Brace Yourself For Another Ugly Quarter'},
 {u'author_name': None,
  u'author_picture': u'http://static.cdn-seekingalpha.com/images/users_profile/000/055/431/medium_pic.png?1379429224',
  u'comments_counts': u'45',
  u'company_name': None,
  u'id': 3272165,
  u'path': u'/article/3272165-weighing-the-week-ahead-what-does-the-greek-crisis-mean-for-financial-markets',
  u'publish_on': 1434863813,
  u'slug': None,
  u'title': u'Weighing The Week Ahead: What Does The Greek Crisis Mean For Financial Markets'},
 {u'author_name': None,
  u'author_picture': u'http://static1.cdn-seekingalpha.com/images/users_profile/003/854/671/medium_pic.png?1428599641',
  u'comments_counts': u'6',
  u'company_name': u'Google Inc.',
  u'id': 3272955,
  u'path': u'/article/3272955-google-a-big-test-lies-ahead-with-the-verticalization-of-youtube',
  u'publish_on': 1434908812,
  u'slug': u'goog',
  u'title': u'Google: A Big Test Lies Ahead With The Verticalization Of YouTube'},
...
...
}]
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. I now understood that this was caused by ajax and maybe needs log-in to access the comment. But I would like to know what I can do to go through these and manage to get the data. Your code seems to only crawl one single page (which I have no idea where it was found) and format it with jason. I am not sure if this is relevant to the question.

Comment: open your page in google chrome and hit `F12` you will find a window where in the network tab you will find these requests.